# Google script to send conditional emails based on cells in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I would like to have generate an email alert when one column is greater than the other. Specifically, column F > column G. Here is what I have so far, any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I do not have much skill writing functions.

```
function readCell() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Watch list");  
    var value = sheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
    var value1 = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
    if(value>value1) MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', 'subject',     'message');
};
```

Currently this only attempts to compare cell F2 to cell G2. Is there a way to make the function compare the entire F column against column G, and generate an email for each individual case where Fx > Gx ?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop all over the range.
first instead of getting the content of one cell you'll need to get the content of all the column:

```
var value = sheet.getRange("F2").getValue();
```

become that

```
var values = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
```

(same for value1)
then you need to create an empty table that will collect the results:

```
var results = [];
```

and now you need to loop throught all the values:

```
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
//do the comparaison and store result if greater for example
}
```

then you may send the result.
all put together it give something like that:

```
function readCell() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Watch list");  
    var values = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getValues();
    var value1s = sheet.getRange("G2:G").getValues();
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      if(values[i]<value1s[i]){
        results.push("alert on line: "+(i+2)); // +2 because the loop start at zero and first line is the second one (F2)
      }
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', 'subject',     results.join("\n"));
};
```

If you want to trigger that function automatically you'll also need to change the way you call the spreadsheet (instead of getActive.... you'll need to use openById)

Comment: This is definitely on the right track!

if(values[i]<value1s[i]){     should be if(values[i]>value1s[i]){    since we want values where F>G right? 

The results are a little strange though. I edited the column values so that all of them should trigger an alert, but only some are. What's even stranger is when I set all the F column values to 300 I get a different set of alerts than when all the F column values are set to 200. Any thoughts @Harold ?